# Restoring the script command

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, binary

I overwrote the binary "script" in the "/usr/bin" directory (ubuntu 16:04), after the script command did not work.

Is there a way to restore the binary, so the command works again?

Comment: [`script` comes from `bsdutils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bin%2Fscript&searchon=contents), just reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The script command apparently is provided by `bsdutils` package ( as per online version of the manual at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/script.1.html     )   , so just reinstall that with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bsdutils`.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the script command from a working 16.04 system, e.g. a Live system on USB.

BTW: It is a bad habit to overwrite (or erase) files that do not work instead of trying to find out *why* thy don't work. Better move it away before overwriting it.